# How to use VML to allow background-image in Outlook with HAML?

Tags: css, email, outlook, haml, vml

I am formatting an e-mail digest using HAML and tables. I would like to be able to set a background-image to a table-cell in my e-mail, but I have found that in order to show a background-image in Outlook, I must use something called VML.

I found this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:rect style="width:540px;height:150px;" strokecolor="none">
     <v:fill type="tile" color="#363636" src="http://www.website.com/background.png" /></v:fill>
   </v:rect>
   <v:shape id="NameHere" style="position:absolute;width:540px;height:150px;">
   <![endif]-->
```

But I have no idea how to get this to work in HAML, if I even can. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Haml will accept element names containing `:`, so you can just use normal Haml syntax:

```haml
/[if gte mso 9]
  %v:rect(style = "width:540px;height:150px;" strokecolor="none")
    %v:fill(type="tile" color="#363636" src="http://www.website.com/background.png")
  %v:shape(id="NameHere" style="position:absolute;width:540px;height:150px;")
```

which produces

```html
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect strokecolor='none' style='width:540px;height:150px;'>
    <v:fill color='#363636' src='http://www.website.com/background.png' type='tile'></v:fill>
  </v:rect>
  <v:shape id='NameHere' style='position:absolute;width:540px;height:150px;'></v:shape>
<![endif]-->
```